# drupal 6 form table spacing issues

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

[image: table output with code shown here]

I wrote a form module where I wanted to make tables of textfields, but their spacing is so far apart from one another as shown in the picture. How can I make them stay closer together? For some reason the rows are spaced very far from one another, as are the columns. I'd like them to be right next to one another as with most HTML tables that are built for websites.

Secondly, is there a way to incorporate forms into theme_table() provided by drupal for regular text content?? The format is really nice for those. 
--> http://coffeeshopped.com/2010/09/drupal-drag-and-drop-tables-in-custom-modules
I should be able to stuff $form into the $header and $row arrays for theme_table(). 
I posted an alternative to this, which is also a question here: [drupal 6 form module not calling hook_theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105655/drupal-6-theme-table-for-form-elements-using-theme-hook)

```
  $form['a1'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Date'),
    '#prefix'=>'<table><tr><td>',
    '#suffix'=>'</td>',
  );
    $form['a2'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Amount Requested'),
    '#prefix'=>'<td>',
    '#suffix'=>'</td>',
  );
     $form['a3'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Amount Recieved'),
    '#prefix'=>'<td>',
    '#suffix'=>'</td></tr>',
  );

  $form['b1'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#prefix'=>'<tr><td>',
    '#suffix'=>'</td>',
  );
    $form['b2'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#prefix'=>'<td>',
    '#suffix'=>'</td>',
  );
      $form['b3'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#prefix'=>'<td>',
    '#suffix'=>'</td></tr>',
  );
  $form['c1'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#prefix'=>'<tr><td>',
    '#suffix'=>'</td>',
  );
    $form['c2'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#prefix'=>'<td>',
    '#suffix'=>'</td>',
  );
     $form['c3'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#prefix'=>'<td>',
    '#suffix'=>'</td></tr></table>',
  );
```

Comment: Hello, Though I am not going to copy your code, edit, test & post again but the solution which I adopted for this is..

Answer (score 0):

Though I am not going to copy your code, edit, test & post again but the solution which I adopted for this is like -

Put some  ID or Class in prefix-suffix of your form element & style them or you just put one Class/ID for the first element of the form & end it at last & write the style for TD/TR for this particular DIV..

You will be able to fix spacing this way..

There can be other way...but this is how I did.

Thanks,

Comment: what about theming? I'm going crazy trying to figure out how to do that correctly here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105655/drupal-6-form-module-not-calling-hook-theme

Comment: When you are building the form, you are using <td><tr> to making table of the input field. Instead of that you can start <div class = ""> in prefix & end </div> in suffix...that will do... Or you can simple insert a empty field at the start of the form with prefix <div id =""> and end the </div> at the end of the form...you will get this table in the div id...for which you can write your CSS...

Comment: Oh... You simply follow the theme which you are using and open the folder of the theme. You will find your style.css..so please write the style in the end of the file...clear the cache & you will see it applied...
If you are using default theme then it would be in THEMES folder in root directory of drupal instance other wise it would be in SITES/ALL/THEMES..